# AngularJS Directives: ngModelCtrl.$parsers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

After looking at a few different custom directives, I have noticed that some people use ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push() and some others use ngModel.$parsers.unshift(). Could someone explain the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) adds to the end of an array.

[`unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) places the new element at the front of the array.

The order matters because parsers are executed in order. From the [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController):

> Array of functions to execute, as a pipeline, whenever the control reads value from the DOM. The functions are called in array order, each passing its return value through to the next. The last return value is forwarded to the $validators collection.

Answer (score 0):

`$parsers.unshift()` put your parser function in the beginning of the list, so it will be executed before all the other, `$parsers.push()` put it in the end.

`$parsers` it is an array object and provides [array functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)